# Can I use existing heater wiring to supply a sub-panel for two circuits?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I'm converting an existing sauna room to infrared. It currently has one 240/30A circuit. I have two heaters and one power supply/controller. Before purchasing I believed the power supply would handle powering both heaters from one on input side, but now I know two circuits are needed (PS has 4 inputs/4 outputs)

Each heater is 13A. Rather than run a 2nd circuit from the subpanel (would be difficult), I am hoping to add a small sub panel to split the 30A into two 15A circuits. The 30A is already coming from a subpanel but I wouldn't be making any changes there.

Is this approach ok or do I need to run a 2nd circuit?
[image: power supply]

[image: Control panel]

[image: heaters][image: outlets for heaters]

[image: heater nameplate]
[image: Wire diagram back of door]

So L1/N1 - L4/N4 on input side, L10/N10 - L40/N40 on output side
240v/30A coming in. I'm getting from this conversation that I'll need to replace the feed side 30A breaker with a 40A or 50A?

Comment: Does the existing circuit have a neutral wire? Also,13a is over limit - should be 12a max for a continuous load on a 15a circuit.

Comment: Where on earth are you?

Comment: When you say power supply could you explain? Running a small sub to break down into individual circuits could be done but the supply/controller if it uses additional power would be questionable.  If there are no motors and you use a sub the field wiring could be 20 amp & breakers but the supply can be 30 amp to the sub your controller cycles the heat control? But if any motors in the system it needs to be rated at 125% as this would be considered fixed heating equipment. This is covered in article 424 of the NEC

Comment: Are the new heaters 13A @ 120V or 13A @ 240V? Makes a big difference in both power available and (unless the controller needs it) need for a neutral.

Comment: @Bob Could you please give the model & specs for the new power supply/control and the two heaters?

Comment: Good advice on the 15A, I'm going to update the 30A breaker on the feed to 40A (that should do it right?)  Correct, no neutral wire. Two hots & ground. The 240V coming into the room is 8 gauge wire. One thing I left out, this feed is already coming from a subpanel for A/C units, just mentioning that in case there's a problem with a subpanel off of a subpanel but hopefully not. The feed to sauna room was original with the house bit just straight 30A circuit

Comment: The power supply is from clearlight sauna, no manufacturer info provided to me but its got 4 inputs and 4 outputs plus a control panel connected via ethernet to PS. Quoting from install guide from clearlight, "each output terminal has max 2400watt/20A capacity when wired 120, 4800 when wired 240" No motors, just some output wires for internal/external lights which I will not use at this time. Yes the PS/controller manages the heat.

Comment: Where on earth are you? – NoSparksPlease 1 hour ago - Florida

Comment: @Bob Link to installation instructions or model number would help clarifying interpretation of issues.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser - Clearlight radiant heater model# JH24-13A. Power supply/controller I don't have any info other than clearlight's item# ID-Cont9600. They have not been willing to give me manufacturer's or deeper manuals which is frustrating. Its capable of 120v or 240 but I had 240 coming into the room already. Heaters are 2400w.

Comment: If you only have 3 wire hot,hot, ground you cannot use 120v devices as they would would use the ground for the return this has been code for over 20 years.

Comment: Can you provide images of labels or name plates and the Inputs and outputs of the controller and heaters?

Comment: Do you have a fridge-sized clearspace sticking out from the wall you can mount the subpanel *to*?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel why do you ask? I plan to put it directly under the power supply box, recessed into wall. Is there a code issue with doing that?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser - uploaded pics to original post including nameplate on heaters. There's not much identifying anything inside the power supply box. Its got 4 circuit boards arranged 2x2, its hard to see from the picture but behind the wires there are 4 small circuit boards. Nothing identifying on them. Orange wires are the output, hard to see but gray wire on input side is the original 240 feed.

Comment: @EdBeal I uploaded some pics that should clear that up. Its purely 240, no 120. I have the two hots coming in the gray wire on input side. My problem is I only get 240 from L10/N10 on output side, L20/N20 is dead. Sales rep told me I need a 2nd circuit.

Comment: Label information makes a **huge** difference. They look like possibly illegal junk (CE, no ETL or UL) but assuming everything is "good", the numbers are much better than I originally thought. They are called "13A" but they are actually 10.4A current draw. 10.4 x 1.25 = 13A. Which means that each one can fit perfectly fine on a 15A circuit, or 2 on a (split) 30A circuit.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Oh boy, illegal junk? Maybe so with how health industry is. The company seems to be foreign based but US base is in Berkley CA. Same heaters are installed in Hippocrates Health institute in Palm Beach & Ritz Carlton Ft Lauderdale, No EMF, and far enough from electric field. But disturbing nonetheless that no UL like you said. That aside, you bring me good news if I can do this without upgrading the breaker on the feed line. Thankyou.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - Wait I do see CE & CB markings on label. I think company is german, Original plugs were euro and I replaced with US 220v/15a

Comment: Aha. CE doesn't mean much by itself, but as I understand it, it can mean *something* for European products. EMF isn't an issue - the basic issue is simple electrical safety. I would definitely want this on a GFCI.

Comment: @Bob -- panels need *clear working space* in front of them by Code (and for practical reasons), although they can share clear working spaces with other pieces of electrical gear (such as your power supply box)

Comment: Yeah, if they were made by a legitimate German company and imported to the US by a US-based subsidiary, they're probably fine.  The CE mark, in Europe, indicates that the manufacturer (if domestic) or importer (if not) tested the device to European standards, and it passed.  The trouble is that here in the US, that mark legally means nothing, and cheap Chinese knockoffs often counterfeit it, so it's wise to be suspicious of them here.

Comment: Also, the UTS mark apparently is an actual testing lab based in China.  They're not recognized as an NRTL (Nationally Recognized Testing Lab) in the US, but they do seem to be recognized in Europe, and even have warnings on their web site about not using fake CE marks.  http://uts-ce.com/en/index.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The posted pictures help a lot. Your heating elements are only 10.4 A each, so you don't need to change the breaker. The 13A in the part number is not the ampere rating.

You need to wire L1 and L2 together and N1 and N2 together in the control box. Each Ln is not indicating a phase but an input to the relays which are all isolated from each other so you have the option to run all the heaters on seperate breakers.

It looks like the equipment is only rated for 20A per circuit. This means that if you draw enough current through one heater to trip the breaker (say during a malfunction) then you may start the controller on fire before the breaker trips. In this case, I would recommend going with the subpanel and two 15 A two pole breakers feeding each of the two inputs you need to power. The only way it would work by pig-tailing is if all components are rated at the breaker capacity up to the point of additional circuit protection.

Comment: You can't simply throw a 15A-rated device on a 30A circuit without down-breakering. There is *some* leeway, depending on the device - e.g., motor loads often will allow a higher breaker in order to account for startup, but 13A on 30A? Not generally a good idea.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact    Wouldn't he be "down-breakering" in the new sub-panel?  But there is another issue derating the 30 amp circuit for continuous use yields a capacity of 24 amps and with 2 13 amp heaters he'd be drawing 26 amps.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Thanks for pointing out that I implied adding a receptacle by using the word "device". I edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson But the load is only 13A on each circuit and he should be able to use a subpanel with two 20A circuits. I edited to add that too.

Comment: The way this is worded is not best and there needs to be clarification of what the actual load is, a “non continuous load” can add up to 30 amps but put 1 fan Motor and everything is considered continuous so the max load would be 24 amps. I started this comment and was called away and there are edits and comments not there when I started but more info is still needed see article 424 fixed heating. This will be the basis on the derate if needed.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Good point. We don't know if the heaters are 120 or 240. No problem if 120 at 13 amps.

Comment: @All - As more information comes in, it is clear that need to modify this answer to fit the situation better. There is a lot of good information in the comments that shouldn't be lost but may seem out of place once I make edits. Do you guys want me to include that comment information in the edits, or should I let them stand? I know some of us can't edit comments after 5 minutes, just delete them. But again, I don't want the valuable information to be lost or to make people retype a modified answer. Suggestions?

Comment: No plans to step down to 120, staying at 240, maybe I confused the issue by quoting the install guide which had instructions for both 120 or 240 heaters, but these are 240

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - no motors, it can run some lighting but not using that. Just two 240 heaters, I added some images to original post

Comment: @ScienceGeyser  Are you saying I only need to pigtail the black to both L1 & L2, and the white to N1 & N2? Seems to be what you are saying but I need to be sure I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @Bob Yes. Since you are not using the 3rd and 4th relays, there is no reason to wire them into the circuit. Control voltage is being taken from L1 so it must be wired for the controller to work. L2 must be wired for output 2 to function.

Comment: Amazing. This is what I was hoping the company rep would tell me when I called. When he said I needed a 2nd circuit it confused me and I can't figure out why he wouldn't suggest what you did. Maybe I didn't make it clear enough that I had 30A? I get your point that I have the option to put a circuit breaker on each 15A branch but if there's no reason to do that I keep it simple. I already had a single heater functioning fine with the one 30A circuit, that proves two won't be damaged. Thanks for the sanity explanation.

Comment: You said in one of your comments that the wire feeding the room was 8 gauge. Is that what is entering the box and terminating on L1 and N1? And is that the same size going out? You need to make sure that all the wire is sized by the breaker since the control doesn't have any circuit protection. This also means the receptacle devices need to be rated for 30 A.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser Yes 8 gauge is on the input side, 10 gauge on output, receptacles are 15A. Sounds like that's a problem, can you explain why?

Comment: Since you have no circuit protection beyond the control box input terminals and the breaker on the branch circuit cannot protect any of the wiring inside the control, you run don't provide protection for lower rated wiring inside the control. If the wiring in the control between the input and relay and relay and output are only 12 gauge wire, they may exceed a safe temperature if 30A flows through a single output during an equipment fault. If you want to protect the smaller wiring inside the control box, you need to add a breaker rated for that wire. You could use two 20 A breakers.

Answer (score 0):

If the owners manual/installation instructions say two 240v 15A circuits are required then you are good to go if you mount a new subpanel with two 240v 15A breakers. Those instructions are part of the *NRTL Listing* and override general NEC provisions.

If the instructions don't specify then IR saunas are normally considered "fixed electric space heating" which NEC 424.3 designates as continuous load, so circuits are calculated at 125% of nameplate. So the branch circuit from a new subpanel would need to be 20A.

For the feeder calculation there is a little, but very little, wiggle room, for the feeder for the new subpanel. Then general rule in 220.51 says the feeder is to be calculated at 100%, but then there is an exception that allows an authority having jurisdiction to allow reduction under cycling conditions. I doubt many local inspector would grant this permission.

Edit: Now seeing the nameplate says 10.4A, not 13A. Then 10.4 x 125% = 13A. It appears the 13A is the circuit requirement, not the actual heater draw. So two 15A receptacles on separate 15A breakers being fed by a 30 feeder should be fine.

Comment: Assuming you are in the US, and 220/30A means 240v 30A three wire (two hots/ground) and when you say the new requires 13A you mean 240v 13A (two hots and a ground), not 120/240v (two hots, neutral, ground) and not two 120v 13A circuits.

Comment: Yes two hots, no neutral. In US. Heater manual says 13A, good to know about the 125%, so I'll plan on swapping the 30A breaker for a 40A. Feed wire is 8 gauge. Thanks for awesome answer, references to the code will help me learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the question of the maximal current matching the existing installation, those IR heaters are most likely not specified for the high temperature and/or high humidity/condensing air inside saunas. Also the IP class for electric installations inside saunas should/must be IP65 or better, at least if a water outlet/shower/faucet is inside the sauna.
And of course, GFCIs are mandatory.

If the sauna was made of glass walls, the 2 IR heaters could be installed at 2 neighbouring sides outside with 2 mirrors at the 2 other sides.